# Right sidebar open by default in shinydashboardPlus

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there any way to have right sidebar open by default in shinydashboardPlus?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
      background = "dark",
      rightSidebarTabContent(
        id = 1,
        title = "Tab 1",
        icon = "desktop",
        active = TRUE,
        sliderInput(
          "obs",
          "Number of observations:",
          min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
        )
      )
    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the css class `control-sidebar-open` to the body tag of your dashboard.

This can be done as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
    ),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
      background = "dark",
      rightSidebarTabContent(
        id = 1,
        title = "Tab 1",
        icon = "desktop",
        active = TRUE,
        sliderInput(
          "obs",
          "Number of observations:",
          min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
        )
      )
    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

Please find some related info [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/654) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/660).

Comment: can the right sidebar also be fixed to be permenently open?

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837262/is-it-possible-to-fix-the-left-and-right-sidebars-in-shinydashboardplus-to-perma/) for future readers.