# R shinydashboardPlus 2.0.0 equivalent of sidebar_fullCollapse (or css)

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

Can someone help me out with the right css code to allow me to

(1) Have the `dashboardControlbar` i.e. the right sidebar (previously known as `rightSidebar` in earlier versions of `shinydashboardPlus` < 2.0.0) to be open on start-up

(2) Have the option to fully collapse the right controlbar when the gears icon is clicked

[image]
*(clicking the gears on the right do not allow collapsing of the right controlbar, left works fine)*

This post follows on from [this one which addresses the above scenario but is only valid for the earlier versions of `shinydashboardPlus` < 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135805/shinydashboardplus-fix-conflicting-css-between-sidebars) there have been [major breaking changed in the latest version of the package and internal functions have been changed](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/shinydashboardPlus.html).

In the example code below I am able to achieve (1) by adding some tags to the body e.g `tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPagePlus(...).`

I cannot achieve (2). In previous versions `sidebar_fullCollapse = TRUE` could be called with `dashboardPagePlus` (now called `dashboardPage`) and this is no longer an argument to the function.

I have tried using a css inspector tool with the new examples in the package (with version 2 run `shinydashboardPlusGallery()`) but cannot figure out how to do it or what the right css is.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
data(iris)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Demo")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "slect",
    label = "Selection Menu",
    selected = "a",
    choices = LETTERS[1:3]
  ),
  p("Write something here..."),
  minified = FALSE
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$script('
      $(".navbar-custom-menu").on("click",function(){
        $(window).trigger("resize");
      })'
  ),
  fluidPage(
    plotOutput(
      "scatter",
      height = "700px",
      width = "100%"
    )
  )
)

controlbar <- dashboardControlbar()

ui <- tags$body(class="skin-blue right-sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", 
                dashboardPage(header,
                              sidebar,
                              body,
                              controlbar
                              # sidebar_fullCollapse = TRUE))
                ))
                        

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, pch = 21)
    cats <- levels(iris$Species)
    cols <- c("red", "blue", "yellow2")
    ind <- lapply(cats, function(z)
      which(iris$Species == z))
    for (i in seq(cats)) {
      points(iris$Petal.Length[ind[[i]]],
             iris$Petal.Width[ind[[i]]],
             pch = 19,
             col = cols[i])
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```r
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2020-10-17 r79346)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinyEffects_0.1.0       styler_1.4.1            
[3] shinyAce_0.4.1           shinyWidgets_0.6.0      
[5] shinyjqui_0.4.0          shiny_1.6.0             
[7] shinydashboardPlus_2.0.0 shinydashboard_0.7.1
```